# Deleting Nodes in a Linked List

Tags: c, list, linked-list

After a lot of effort, I've managed to piece together a function that deletes some node from my linked list. But, out of sheer interest, I would like to find out how you can go about deleting the first node from the list, i.e. the head.

My program asks for a letter to delete, so for example.
Hello is stored in the list, the user inputs H for deletion, so that now the list is ello
At the moment with my code, the program crashes obviously as if H is deleted, there is no head, and the program doesn't know where to go to look for the list.

Below is my current implementation, any clues or hints on how to modify this code( I would like to keep it similar to how I have) to allow Head Node Deletion would be much appreciated!.

EDIT: In response to below

```
FullList DeleteNode(FullList temp, char c) {
FullList remember;
FullList ptr;
while (temp.head->c != c) {
    remember.head = temp.head;
    temp.head = temp.head->next;
}
ptr.head = temp.head->next;
free(temp.head);
remember.head->next = ptr.head;
return temp;
}

int main(void) {
FullList List;
char c, s;
List.head = NULL;

while ((c=getchar()) != '.') {
    List = addToEnd(List, c);
}
scanf(" %c", &s);
List = DeleteNode(List, s);
while (List.head != NULL) {
    printf("%c", List.head->c);
    List.head = List.head->next;
}
return 0;
}
```

---

```
typedef struct List {
 char c;
 struct List *next;
}List;

typedef struct {
 List *head;
 List *tail;
}FullList;

 List *insertList(char c, List *t1) {
  List *t = (List*)calloc(1, sizeof(List));
  t->c = c ;
  t->next = t1;
 return t;
 }

FullList addToEnd(FullList c, char element) {
 if (c.head == NULL) { 
    c.head = c.tail = insertList(element, NULL);
 }else {
    c.tail->next = insertList(element, NULL);
    c.tail = c.tail->next;
 }
 return c;
} 

void DeleteNode(FullList temp, char c) {
 FullList remember;
 FullList ptr;
 while (temp.head->c != c) {
    remember.head = temp.head;
    temp.head = temp.head->next;
 } 
 ptr.head = temp.head->next;
 free(temp.head);
 remember.head->next = ptr.head;
} 


int main(void) {
 FullList List;
 char c, s;
 List.head = NULL;

 while ((c=getchar()) != '.') {
    List = addToEnd(List, c);
 }
 scanf(" %c", &s);
 DeleteNode(List, s);
 while (List.head != NULL) {
    printf("%c", List.head->c);
    List.head = List.head->next;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it without changing your existing code.

You're passing your `FullList` struct to your `DeleteNode()` function. This means that any changes to that struct are not visible back in `main` - the function is getting a *copy* of it.

You would need to change `DeleteNode()` to accept a pointer:

```
void DeleteNode(FullList *temp, char c)
```

Then when calling it `main()` you would do:

```
DeleteNode(&List, s);
```

By doing this, you can change the value of `temp->head` in your function and it will be visible back in `main()`

```
temp->head = temp->head->next;
```

**Edit:** The logic you'll need is:

- Check to see if `temp->head->c == c`
- If yes, replace `temp->head` with `temp->head->next`
- else assign `temp->head` to a temp pointer `*previous`. Assign `temp->head->next` to a pointer `*current`. Loop through the list, moving both pointers. When you find a match in `current->c`, assign `current->next` to `previous->next` and `free()` the `current` node.

Comment: I modified the code as you suggested, but now, it deletes everything up until the letter that was input. i.e. Abcde, input c, de is printed

Comment: Please see my edit if possible, I have returned the FullList as opposed to using Pointers but get the same result, it deletes everything up until the letter I enter.

Comment: @user1048116 - I explained now to change the value of `temp->head`, I didn't do your homework for you ;) You need to construct logic that starts at the head and looks for a match. As a hint, you're going to need two pointers - `*previous` and `*current`. You need to start at the head, keeping track of the previous and current node and look for your match in `current->c`. When you find the node you want to delete you have to assign `current->next` to `previous->next` then `free` the `current` node. There's no need to return anything from this function - you're modifying the struct via a pointer

Comment: Sorry - and the logic has to include a special case for the head needing to be replaced.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, in fact I managed to get it working with my current code by just adding an IF statement if what was being searched happen to be the Head Node, and dumped the rest of the code in a ELSE clause.

Comment: @user1048116 - Yes, you *can* do it that way ... but what you'll find is that no one does; it's a terrible approach because of the unneeded inefficiency of all the copying you're doing in and out of the function as well as all the assignments you're doing to build a new list inside the function. Let's just say that if I were teaching the class, that solution would not receive high marks even though it functions. In C terms, it's a but of a Rube Goldberg approach.

Answer (score 1):

The way it is now, inside `DeleteNode`, when you change the argument, it only changes the local variable, not the one outside the function.

You either have to pass the `FullList` to `DeleteNode` by pointer so that modifications done to it will be visible to the caller, or modify a local one and return it, and the caller must assign the returned `FullList` to its list.

Either way, the changes made by `DeleteNode` must become visible to the caller.

Comment: @user1048116 as Brian Roach was saying, you have to either have two pointers (one to the current and one to the previous, whose `next` pointer you must fix) or just perform the checks on `temp.head->next->c` instead of `temp.head->c` and have a special case where `head->c` is the desired character.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, in fact I managed to get it working with my current code by just adding an IF statement if what was being searched happen to be the Head Node, and dumped the rest of the code in a ELSE clause.